# Finding $E[X]$ in two ways where $X$ is the number of white balls selected when balls are chosen at random from an urn

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

I do my homework but I understand how to find the probability of this exercise,
Could somebody give an idea or detail me.

> The problem, let $X$ denote the number of white balls selected when $k$ balls are chosen at random from an urn containing $n$ white and $m$ black balls.
>
> Let, for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, k; j = 1, 2, \ldots , n,$
>
> $X_i=1$ if the $i^{th}$ ball selected is white, $0$ otherwise.
>
> and  $Y_i=1$ if the $j^{th}$ white ball is selected, $0$ otherwise.
>
> Compute $E[X]$ in two ways by expressing $X$ first as a function of the $X_i$
> ’s and then
> of the $Y_j$ ’s.

Then, we have to find first $E[X]=E[X_1]+E[X_2]+\cdots+E[X_k]$

and $E[X]=E[Y_1]+E[Y_2]+\cdots+E[Y_n]$.

That my question, how we find each $E[X_i]$ and $E[X_j]$?

Comment: The probability that a given ball is selected is $\frac k{m+n}$.  The probability that a randomly selected ball is white is $\frac n{m+n}$.

Comment: @lulu your answer would allow to pick more than n white balls if k>n